# How to retrieve nested object in JSon respond with spring boot jpa

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa

I have an entity Product that has a nested object Category. When retrieving the object Product in Json response, the nested object Category is not present. But I have the complete complete object in console log.

How can I do to have the nested Category object in Json response?

My files:
Product.java

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Product {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

@Column(name="code")
@NotNull
private String code;

@Column(name="intitule")
@NotNull
private String intitule;

@Column(name="prixachat")
@NotNull
private double prixAchat;

@Column(name="prixvente")
@NotNull
private double prixVente;

@Column(name="qtitestock")
@NotNull
private int quantiteStock;

@Column(name="isservice")
@NotNull
private boolean isSservice;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Categorie categorie;

@Transient
private int categorieId;

}
```

Category.java

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Categorie {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name="intitule")
@NotNull
private String intitule;    
}
```

JSon Response:

```
[ {
"id" : "15e87d3f-576c-4e29-bc31-c456638c19e0",
"code" : "3716",
"intitule" : "ezpqku",
"prixAchat" : 940.0,
"prixVente" : 6939.0,
"quantiteStock" : 311
}, {
"id" : "1c4c0404-439c-4b48-abf0-b88214228124",
"code" : "3299",
"intitule" : "yzssxt",
"prixAchat" : 221.0,
"prixVente" : 5293.0,
"quantiteStock" : 482
}, {
"id" : "5c9d4b36-eb99-4cc1-917e-831d7677dde3",
"code" : "1225",
"intitule" : "pufibk",
"prixAchat" : 74.0,
"prixVente" : 8738.0,
"quantiteStock" : 581
}]
```

Console log:

```
products : [Product(id=15e87d3f-576c-4e29-bc31-c456638c19e0, code=3716,    intitule=ezpqku, prixAchat=940.0, prixVente=6939.0, quantiteStock=311, isSservice=false, categorie=Categorie(id=1, intitule=hthfxscqmm), categorieId=0), Product(id=1c4c0404-439c-4b48-abf0-b88214228124, code=3299, intitule=yzssxt, prixAchat=221.0, prixVente=5293.0, quantiteStock=482, isSservice=false, categorie=Categorie(id=3, intitule=qsvigcwbrx), categorieId=0)
```

Comment: I don't see any `category` in your json

Comment: Is there a getter for categorie?

Comment: Did JPA retrieve the related object? I'm not talking about JSON. JPA does not retrieve JSON. It retrieves objects. This is a process known as "debugging". You haven't even posted the code to retrieve the object ...

Comment: yes, JPA retrieves the related object. What you see in console log is a print of list of products by JPA.

Comment: Yes JB Nizet, there is a getter for Categorie, generated by lombok.

Comment: So the problem is nothing to do with JPA then, since, in your words, it retrieves the object. So it is solely taking those object and converting to JSON ...